# How to check if a class is capable of implementing an interface at runtime in Java (JDK 17)

Tags: java, reflections

I need to determine whether a class is capable of implementing an interface when it does not explicitly implement that interface. I would like to determine this at runtime, I am using reflections to gather classes.

For example:

Lets say I have the following class:

```
public class Clazz {
    public void doSomething() {
        // ... do it
    }
}
```

And the following interface:

```
public interface ClazzInterface {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

Clazz does not implement ClazzInterface, however it is compatible with ClazzInterface and could implement it without any modification. I am looking for a way to check this at runtime.

Something like:

```
boolean canImplement = Clazz.class canImplement ClazzInterface.class
```

Is this possible either through a built in library or method or some logic I could write myself?

I have tried using reflections `isAssignableFrom` and this does not work, returning `false` for the above example.

Comment: How did you try `isAssignableFrom`? It [should be the way to go](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_isassignablefrom.htm).

Comment: @daniu are you sure that [`Class::isAssignableFrom` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) should work? IIRC, `isAssignableFrom(...)` checks the object hierarchy. Since the class in question does not `implements` the interface, I think this would not work.

Comment: Clarify compatible, the way you think it is, it isn't. Also you can use a Reflection API to look into a Class details. Or you searching for the library to do it for you?

Comment: It is definitively possible to implement a check for this; the compiler does this check (otherwise it would not be able to find certain errors when we implement an interface). I wonder, however, what the end goal here is. We'd need to either manipulate the bytecode of the (already compiled) class, or modify the (source code of the) class and recompile. This smells like an [XY problem (`xyproblem.info`)](https://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Turing85 The end goal is to identify whether a class exactly matches an interface. So what I'm building is a library that is being used to auto test code that students are tasked with writing. Students annotate their classes with a specific annotation which I then search for using reflections. I want to validate that the class they have written meets the criteria that was given to them in the task.

Comment: ... Why not give them the interface and enforce that their code implements the interface?

Comment: @Turing85 Good question, so in this instance the students are not told what the correct return type is for a method, part of the task is to determine the most appropriate return type and giving them the interface would reveal this.

Comment: Then an alternative idea would be to write some code that manipulates the source code to add the `implements SomeInterface` code fragment (from what I read, It should be fairly simple with a bash script, or an OpenRewrite recipe).

Comment: Yet another idea is to let the Interface return `Object`. We can then test the runtime type of the returned value with `instanceof ...` or `.getClass().getCanonocalName()` or ... as part of the test procedure. Of course, we should then mention that the interface returns `Object` because part of the exercise is to determine the return type.

Comment: Voting to re-open. Closing for "seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries" is an over-reaction and a misinterpretation. This is actually a question about the intricacies of using reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such concept of "is capable of implementing" an interface. A class either does (or does not) implement an interface. **However**, you can use *reflection* to dynamically call some method. It has caveats and limitations (of course). For example, it's usually slow. But here is a `doSomething` with "duck-typing".

```
public static final void doSomething(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return;
    }
    Class<?> cls = o.getClass();
    try {
        Method m = cls.getMethod("doSomething", new Class<?>[] {});
        if (m != null) {
            m.invoke(o, new Object[] {});
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note the line `if (m != null)`, that does check if `doSomething` is available in the actual instance `o`. You could test for the presence of all necessary methods in the same manner.

Comment: I think this should solve it, for the functionality I need. Thanks.

Comment: `cls.getMethod` will **never** return `null`. A `NoSuchMethodException` is thrown if the method does not exist.

Comment: Also, you can make use of varargs for the argument types: `cls.getMethod("doSomething")` is equivalent to what you typed. You want to reflectively get an `equals` method? Just use `cls.getMethod("equals", Object.class)`.

Comment: *`There is no such concept of "is capable of implementing" an interface. A class either does (or does not) implement an interface.`*  I disagree.  Imo, `is capable` means that you could  recompile the class to implement the interface without error, requiring no further modification of the class. This might be accomplished by reflective analysis of all aspects of the interface methods to see if they match those same methods in the class.

Comment: And I don't believe this would require using an object of the class  but just using `Class/interface` interogation.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem statement

OP [clarified in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77071815/how-to-check-if-a-class-is-capable-of-implementing-an-interface-at-runtime-in-ja#comment135869513_77071815) that the goal is to build an evaluation system for exercises given to students, I see some approaches that do not require reflection.

#### Approach 1: return `Object`

We can release the interface-definition to the students, but replace the return-type with `Object`. We can then check the runtime-type of the return value via `instanceof` or [`Class::isAssignableFrom` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) (or really any other way we see fit).

#### Approach 2: Modify the source code to add `implements <interface>`

There are many way we could do this, e.g. a simple bash-script like

```
find \
  src/main/java \
  -type f \
  -name "*.java" \
  -exec \
    sed \
      -i \
      's/^\(.*class\s\+Bar\)\s\+{.*$/\1 implements Foo {/g' \
    {} \;
```

We can then incorporate this script in a plethora of ways in our build-process. The downside of this approach is that it is OS-depndent.

I would like to highlight another approach using [OpenRewrite (`docs.openrewrite.org`)](https://docs.openrewrite.org/), which is OS-independent. OpenRewrite allows us, among other things, to formulate simple rules for refactoring in a declarative way. In our example, we want to replace the string `class <classname>` with `class  <classname> implements <interfacename>`. If we assume the name of the interface to be `Foo` and the name of the class to be `Bar`, a OpenRewrite recipe may look like this:

```
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: de.turing85.AddFooInterfaceToBarClass
displayName: Add the Foo interface to the Bar class.
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.text.FindAndReplace:
      find: (?<classdef>class\s+Bar)\s+\{
      replace: ${classdef} implements Foo {
      regex: true
      filePattern: src/main/java/**/*.java
```

Since OpenRewrite provides a [maven- (`docs.openrewrite.org`)](https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/rewrite-maven-plugin) and a [gradle-plugin (`docs.openrewrite.org`)](https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/gradle-plugin-configuration), we can simply incoroprate it in our build-process.

A POC can be found in [this `github.com` repository](https://github.com/turing85/openrewrite-example).